# How can I open pdf files by default with foxit?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pdf

I'm new to ubuntu as I come from Win7. In win7 I was using Foxit Reader to open the pdf documents.

Searching online I found [this method](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/08/create-pdf-with-foxit-reader-on-ubuntu-14-04/) to install Foxit.

```
cd Downloads/  
tar -xvf FoxitReader-1.1.0.tar.bz2  
cd 1.1-release/  
./FoxitReader
```

As you can see, in order to open foxit I have to run it from `cmd`, but I'll like to automatically open the pdf files with Foxit. How can I do that?

Comment: Foxit offers a .deb file as well on the same site (which should install by double click) but both that one and the one you mention do not run on Ubuntu. Any special reason why you want to use foxit?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: it runs in ubuntu, but I can't open pdf files automatically with it. Exerytime I need to use it, I have t lunch it from cmd and then to File->Open from it's gui.

Comment: try evince `evince pdfname.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to look for the *.desktop file FoxitReader.desktop and add *% F* at the end of the line starting with *Exec*

More in details: in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine I found the file in the following folder

```
cd /$HOME/FoxitSoftware/FoxitReader/
vim FoxitReader.desktop
```

The file initially was like this:

```
  1 [Desktop Entry]
  2 Name=Foxit Reader
  3 Comment=View pdf documents
  4 Keywords=pdf;octet-stream;
  5 StartupNotify=true
  6 Terminal=false
  7 Type=Application
  8 #Icon=FoxitReader
  9 X-GNOME-DocPath=
 10 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
 11 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=FoxitReader
 12 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
 13 X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.14.1
 14 Categories=GNOME;Viewer;Graphics;2DGraphics;VectorGraphics;
 15 MimeType=application/pdf;application/octet-stream;
 16 Exec=/home/pbirol/FoxitSoftware/FoxitReader/FoxitReader.sh
 17 Icon=/home/pbirol/FoxitSoftware/FoxitReader/images/FoxitReader.png
```

I modified **only** the 16th line and added %F at the end:

```
 16 Exec=/home/pbirol/FoxitSoftware/FoxitReader/FoxitReader.sh %F
```

Since most of my *.desktop files are in the folder /usr/share/applications/ I also copied it there, just to be sure (however, I am not sure this part is necessary)

```
sudo cp FoxitReader.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Now FoxitReader is part of the list of programs recognized by ubuntu in the "open with" list, so I just went to a pdf file, `right-clicked > Open with > View all applications` and chose FoxitReader

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go where is your PDF file, click with the right button, and then click on "Open with". Hope that it solved your problem =D

Comment: I don't have Foxit in the "Open with" menu neither in Porperties->Open with tab section